# Move .keras directory in Ubuntu

Tags: ipython, keras

When I'm in `ipython` and try to import `keras`, I get the error `No space left on device: /home/username/.keras`. How can I change this so that Keras does not use my HOME directory, and instead use `/data/username/`? I did the same for the directory `~/.ipython`. I moved it to the desired location and then did `export IPYTHONDIR=/data/username/.ipython`, can I do something similar with Keras? More generally, how can I do this for any app that wants to use HOME?

Note: Please don't give answers like "you can clean your home" etc. I am asking this for a reason. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to move it to a different disk and create a symlink in home pointing to it?

Comment: Problem is that Keras will try to create the directory at import time. Such directory does not exist yet.

Comment: so what happens if the directory already exists?

Comment: Keras package will store some temporary files there I believe. I am not sure because I haven't used it thoroughly yet, maybe it's for configuration settings as in the case of ipython. When I couldn't run ipython, it was due to the same problem: the message was `No space left on device: /home/username/.ipython`. I moved the directory and exported the variable as said, and it began working.

Comment: Mhm, this all makes sense, but I don't see how this invalidates the suggestion with symlinking the directory to another disk. Have you already tried that? Did it not work?

Comment: @cel Yes it worked. I had to symlink other stuff as well later though. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think keras is the only problem. If you are using theano as a backend, it will create `$HOME/.theano/` as well.

One dirty trick is to `export HOME=/data/username/`, but other program than keras or ipython will also treat `/data/username/` as `$HONE`. To avoid that, you can do this locally by calling `HOME=/data/username/ ipython` or `HOME=/data/username/ python kerasProgram.py`.